# Open and write in txt file from Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with code, I want my macro to open a .txt file and write only 1-9 rows(copy from Excel) in one  txt file and then open next .txt file and write 9-18 and so on until data in the excel rows is finished under each column.
Below code only paste 1-9 rows from Excel to Txt file and stop.
So it means if I have 36 rows in Excel(A1-A36) it should create 3 txt files each with 9 rows only.

```
Sub env_gen()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim linetext As String
    Dim my_range As Range
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Monday123" & ".txt"
    Open filename For Output As #1
    Set my_range = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A9")
    For i = 1 To 9
        For j = 1 To 1
            linetext = IIf(j = 1, "", linetext & ",")
        Next j
        Print #1, linetext
    Next i
    Close #1

   MsgBox ("File is created")

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting this part to do? `For j = 1 To 1` - `j` will always be `1`, so `linetext` will always be an empty string.

Comment: Do you have a question about something?  You may want to indent your code properly.

Comment: I will fix this part of the code, I want help with loop, to open multiple txt files and paste next number of excel rows on it.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over a range, you can use a loop and put the index inside the range address. Eg. `For i = 1 to 9: Cells(i, 1) = ...`. This loop can also use the ranges size as a parameter to ensure you loop over the whole range and only the range (no extra). Eg. `For i = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count`.

When looping within a loop, you can also use the outer loops index as a parameter for the inner loop. Eg. `For i = 1 to 36 Step 9: For j = i to i + 8`

Here is an example of those techniques implemented with your code:

```vb
Sub env_gen()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim linetext As String
    Dim CurrentStep As Long
    
    Dim my_range As Range
    Set my_range = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A36")
    
    For i = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count Step 9
        CurrentStep = CurrentStep + 1
        
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Monday123 (" & CurrentStep & ").txt"
        Open filename For Output As #1
        
        For j = i To i + 8
            linetext = my_range.Cells(i).Text & IIf(j <> i + 8, "", ",")
            Print #1, linetext
        Next j
        
        Close #1
    Next i

   MsgBox ("Files are created")

End Sub
```

Comment: kindly check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242746/how-to-use-range-array-to-speed-up-copy-data-on-condition-excel-vba

Comment: @Waleed_wwm What was that link to? I am checking it now and it is deleted.

Comment: my question was about using arrays to speed copy , but it was not clear enough and devoted, so I deleted it and opened a one new (it already got answers) , if you wish this the link it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244852/how-to-speed-data-copy-from-sheet1-to-other-sheets-by-using-arrays-excel-vba/68245678?noredirect=1#comment120633227_68245678